# How to plot y=z, with x=1 in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot $y=z$ with $x=1$ in three dimensional plot. How can one do this in Mathematica?

Comment: I find it so weird (wrong?) that `RegionPlot3D` does not do the job here. For starters, `RegionPlot3D` does not accept a region as an argument, and expects only a *"logical combination of inequalities"*. Furthermore, *"`RegionPlot3D` can in general only find regions of positive measure; it cannot find regions that are just lines or points."*. So it's useless for this 1D region in 3D space.

Answer (score 4):

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[{y == z, x == 1}, {x, y, z}], 
 BaseStyle -> {Thick, Red}, Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That would be a line. You can plot it like so:

```
max = 5;
ParametricPlot3D[{1,t,t},{t,-max,max},AxesLabel->{"x","y","z"}]
```